# Подключение библиотек boost к visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost

Я установил себе на компьютер boost.Прошел все этапы установки по гайду из интернета,подключил скомпилированные библиотеки в cpp-properties.json. Теперь,если я пишу ,к примеру: #include <boost/random/mersenne twister.hpp> ошибка подключения не возникает.Однако, когда я компилирую и пробую запустить вылетает ошибка. Почитав в интернете,я понял,что нужно добавить еще и в task.json путь к библиотекам в lib,но проделав данные манипуляции ошибка все равно остается. Выдает ,что путь к библиотекам не удается найти. Можете помочь разобраться,что нужно прописать для нормальной работы boost'а?
UPD: Вот файл cpp-properties.json

```js
{ "configurations":[
  {
    "name":"Win32",
    "includePath":[
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "C:/boost/include/boost-1_68",
    "C:/boost/lib"
    ],
    "defines":[
    "_DEBUG",
    "UNICODE",
    "_UNICODE"],
    "compilerPath":"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
    "cStandard":"gnu++14",
    "intelliSence Mode":"gcc-x64"
    }
    ],
    "version":4
}
```

А это tasks.json

```js
{"tasks":[
    {"type":"cppbuild",
    "label":"C/C++:g++.exe build active file",
    "command":"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
    "args":[
    "-g",
    "${File}",
    "-o",
    "${file Dirname}\\${file BasenameNotExtension}.exe",
    "-I",
    "C:/boost",
    "-L",
    "C:/boost/lib/libboost_random-mgw81-mt-d-x64-1_68.a"],
    "option":{
    "cwd":"C:\\MinGW\\bin"
    },
    "problem Matcher":[
    "gcc"],
    "group":{
    "kind":"build",
    "isDefault":true
    },
    "detail":"Generated task by Debugger"
    }
    ],
    "version":"2.0.0"
    }
}
```

Я последовал совету из комментарием и добавил `-L`-флаг. Компиляция проходит,но когда я запускаю в терминале,появляется ошибка. Пишет,что путь к библиотеке,которую я подключил не найден. Например,если я напишу `#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>`. Можете указать еще раз,что я не так сделал?

Comment: Так покажите свои json файлы и ошибки. Мы ж не телепаты.

Comment: Как был установлен `boost` ? 

Вы можете повторить процедуру установки через `vcpkg`? Инструкции установки прилагаются на [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=msvc-160). 

Какая у вас целевая система? х64? У вас точно был он скомпилирован под x64?

Comment: То, что вы используете VSC - не очень важно. Важнее - какой стоит компилятор, и на всякий случай - какая ОС.

Comment: Извиняюсь,забыл написать,что компилятор MinGW.Система 64x. Вот поэтому гайду я устанавливал (https://gist.github.com/zrsmithson/0b72e0cb58d0cb946fc48b5c88511da8).
Вот кусок tasks.json
 `"type": "shell",`
            `"label": "g++.exe build active file",`
            `"command": "C:/mingw-w64/bin/g++.exe",`
            `"args":`
                `"${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp",`
                `"-o",`
                `"${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",`
                `"-I",`
                `"C:/boost"`

Comment: Забыли прилинковать буст: `-LC:/путь/к/библиотекам -lboost_random`. Путь - к папке, к которой лежат `.a`-файлы. Разные части буста требуют разных флагов `-l...`, а некоторые - никакх. Этот - для boost random.

Comment: Спасибо,завтра попробую сделать так как вы сказали. Просто комп на работе,где VS code установлен. Платный софт проблемка для предприятия)

Comment: @EOF теперь вроде все указал,чего не хватало. Не можешь подсказать,что именно я сделал не так ?Просто мне нужен Вихрь Мерсенна позарез для реализации метода Монте-Карло

Comment: *"путь к библиотеке,которую я подключил не найден"* Путь к какой-то `.dll`? Она должна быть где-то в папке с бустом, скопируйте ее в папку с экзешником.

Comment: Но вообще, если вам нужен вихрь мерсенна, то он уже есть в стандартной библиотеке. Можно обойтись и без буста.